# Webpack does not generate bundle file on npm run

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Greetings one and all,

After having made a React application, I decided to dive in deeper into Webpack.
I am rather new at the whole npm automation scene and after having followed a cookbook and various tutorials, I just cannot let `npm run dev` bundle my application. It generates a bundle.js perfectly fine when I run `webpack`, but what appealed to me was having webpack generate a physical file whenever I change something. Gulp and Grunt can do this for me, but I'd like to get it to work with webpack as well.

So, without further ado, some code. I run `npm run dev` which is defined like so (`package.json`, just the scripts part*):

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build"
  }
```

With the following Webpack configuration:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/main.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '/js/bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
                new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
            ], ["normal"], "loader")
    ]
};
```

Cases:
`webpack`: Bundles my application into dist/js/bundle.js perfectly fine.
`webpack-dev-server`: Seems to stream a memory bundle from my JS perfectly fine, but does not generate a bundle on disk.
`npm run dev`: Starts the webpack server, but does not result in a bundle, nor does my application run, resulting in a **Cannot GET/** error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried variations on the config, but to no avail.. And just to be complete, I will show my directory structure:

```
./project
    ./dist
        ./js
            ./bundle.js
    ./src
        ./js
            ./main.js
./package.json
./webpack.config.js
```

Once again, thanks for the assist!

Comment: I get that. What I find interesting, is that it does generate a bundle.js file when running the `webpack` command. From the sources I've read, including that command in the package.json -> scripts node, should make it possible to include that functionality when running `npm run dev`.

Comment: So the issue is that `webpack-dev-server` works, but `npm run dev` doesn't? Are you calling `webpack-dev-server` with the same arguments in both cases?

Comment: *"What I find interesting, is that it does generate a bundle.js file when running the webpack command."* well, that's what the `webpack` command is supposed to do. They are different commands with different purposes. Whether you invoke them directly or via `npm run *` doesn't make a difference. Not sure I understand what the issue is.

Comment: What I would like, is that instead of re-bundling and streaming with webpack-dev-server, is to have an actual bundle.js file when running `npm dev run`. As https://christianalfoni.github.io/react-webpack-cookbook/Getting-started.html includes a build argument in the scripts that calls to `webpack`, I assume webpack can make that physical bundle instead of streaming it. Since it does make a physical path when just entering `webpack`. Do note that I'm not that advanced in npm and/or webpack and am just trying to understand/get it to work :) Since I do like the tech.

Comment: If you simply want incremental builds and not the dev server, pass the `watch` option to webpack: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#watch-mode-watch .

Comment: I'd like both to be honest. `webpack --watch` does seem to recompile, but without a local server. Is what I want (http server, physical bundling) that weird? I'm asking because if what you say is true, I might as well keep relying on Gulp or Grunt for my physical bundles.

Comment: The dev server doesn't write to disk and I don't think there is any option to make it so. You could write your own small script that starts up a local server and refreshes automatically on file changes, if having a bundle on disk is really needed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that. For now I still need that actual file. Guess I'll keep my gulp watch active as well.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to wrongly written scripts in package.json file. Replace your scripts with the below. It is because you are not providing the correct path to your bundle.js file which is need to be create. "-p" means to read the entry and output keys of webpack.config.js. Then run this cmd: `$ npm run build`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build"
  }
```

Comment: This is factually wrong. `-p` means to optimize for [p]roduction: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/3d653290fafe385277b48e5a36807124618b9561/bin/convert-argv.js#L18-L21

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem was with package.json under that "scripts"

Here is the fix:

Inside your package.json file, under script add the following:

> "scripts": {
>      "start": "webpack-dev-server", 
>      "build": "webpack -p"
>    }

First I ran the build then start.

> yarn build

if you first build then your bundle.js file will be created and after that you can use this command:

> yarn start

Instead of yarn, you can also use npm